# How to filter search results without using IN operator in SQL request in PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress

I use search filters (from Mikado) and I have problem with sql + php statement.

```
$where[] = "{$wpdb->prefix}terms.slug IN (".implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($this->tourTypes), '%s')).")";
```

This line allow to dynamic display trips which have: category1 OR category2 OR category3.

I would like to change it for something like: category1 AND category2 AND category3.

Do you know any alternatives for IN? What the data format in new query should be?

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple:

```php
$catConds = [];
for($i=0; $i <= count($this->tourTypes); $i++) {
    $catConds[] = "{$wpdb->prefix}terms.slug = $i";
}

$where[] = implode(' AND ', $catConds);
```